# Microsoft Botbuilder location: On Click Address selection with multiple results returned

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, web-chat

I have to make map images clickable,
[image]
currently our bot was implemented as above(selecting location by giving numbers as input). Now i have to remove numbers from images and make images clickable which should produce same result as number input.

reference: [BotBuilder-Location](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location), [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

Comment: When you say you want to remove numbers from images, do you mean you don't want those dropped pins to show up in the centers of the maps? Or do you mean you don't want the text to show up under the images? Do you still want the addresses to show up? Do you still want to allow the user to type a number?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I got solution for part of the issue(mainly needed) i mean clicking images. I just handled it in the backend, but i am not sure about removing numbers or pins from the images.

Comment: So you're saying you've made the images clickable but you still need to remove the numbers? I'd like to help but you haven't answered my questions. When you say you want to remove numbers from images, do you mean you don't want those dropped pins to show up in the centers of the maps? Or do you mean you don't want the text to show up under the images? Do you still want the addresses to show up? Do you still want to allow the user to type a number?